# Short connection time at Amsterdam airport

Tags: short-connections, ams

I am traveling from Mumbai to Portland through Amsterdam airport. My layover time at Amsterdam is 1 hour 40 minutes; will this be enough time to catch my flight to Portland?

Comment: Standard question: single ticket or two separate tickets ? Plenty of time on a single ticket, very difficult for two separate tickets.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Minimum connection times for overseas flights is 50 minutes.  Just flew through with a 65 minute connection and plenty of time to spare.

Comment: Just to add here that airline reservation systems know the minimum transit time required and will not book transit flights that cannot be boarded in reasonable time.

Comment: Please consider to get to locate your gate as soon as you can, Schipol is not famous for having the best indications.